# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined" of jquery calendar in the crome.

Can any one explain the reason for this?

Comment: You should add the relevant code of yours ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate Fullcalendar when script was loaded in document ready callback function for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
```

Comment: Hello This problem is only in the Windows Crome. The jquery calender displayed on the top corner of the site.

Comment: Now I have get another error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
"

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the error is of the form Cannot call method 'X' of undefined, it means that whatever object you are attempting to call X from does not exist.